# How to skip a column when reading a CSV file - Python

Tags: python, csv

So in my CSV i have peoples names as the first row and i'm trying to get the average of 3 numbers on the columns 1-3. (not the first column though) Is there a way to skip a column so that i can just pull out columns 1-3? here is my code for getting the average. Any help would be much appreciated. So just to be clear on what i want:
I want to skip a column so that i can successfully get the mean average from columns 1-3.

```
        if order ==("average score"):
            with open("data.csv") as f:
                reader = csv.reader(f)
                columns = f.readline().strip().split(" ")
                numRows = 0
                sums = [1] * len(columns)

                for line in f:
                # Skip empty lines
                    if not line.strip():
                        continue

                values = line.split(" ")
                for i in range(len(values)):

                    sums[i] += int(values[i])
                    numRows += 1

                for index, summedRowValue in enumerate (str(sums)):
                    print (columns[index], 1.0 * summedRowValue / numRows)
```

Comment: All you should have to do is change your range to start at 1 instead of 0, to skip the first column:      for i in range(1, len(values)):

Comment: FWIW, you instantiate a CSV reader, but never use it...

Comment: Thankyou all, the CSV reader i just realised was me experimenting with things, my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you should have to do is change your range to start at 1 instead of 0, to skip the first column:

`for i in range(1, len(values)):`

Comment: No quite sure, I  should wait until he clarifies

Comment: Thankyou so much, this work's however i have another problem now, but would like to have a crack at it my self.